# CURL local interface (smart bulb)

Tags: curl, networking, terminal, lan, lifx

How do i curl a local interface (smart bulb) with binary data from my lan?

From mac terminal

```
curl --request POST --data-binary "31000014aff56f57d073d521437000000000000000000249000000000000000066000000007d92e1ba852bac0d00000000" 10.0.0.29:56700
```

Doesn't work.

The binary packet is correct according to the interface binary api.
The address and port are of the smart bulb.

Are there any special headers or properties to set when curling a wifi interface?

Thanks
Asaf

Comment: That's a long ascii string, not binary data... (and `--request POST` is superfluous there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited

Switched to netcat. This cmd worked for me

```
echo "\x2a\x00\x00\x34\xb4\x3c\xf0\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x75\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00" | socat - udp-datagram:255.255.255.255:56700,broadcast
```

Thanks for the comment.